# How to add Responsive Design in my own Video mp4?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new in this topic and my problem is that I cannot resize my own video for all devices.
Since I would need to add some code to make Responsive design, Could anybody help me to fix it?

My html and CSS code is the following

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="index.css" rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>VR Salud</title>
   <style>
   html, body { margin: 0; padding:0; overflow: hidden; }
   h1 { color:white; position:absolute; top:95%; z-index:100; width:100%; text-align: center;; transform: translate(0,-100%); font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: 100; letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: lowercase; font-size: 30px; }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <video width="1920" height="1080" loop id="video_sample">
    <source src="VRHealthWeb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>

</div>
/*<button id = "btn" onclick = button_action();> Play Here </button>;


<script type="text/javascript">
var store_video = document.getElementById('video_sample');
var btn_store = document.getElementById('btn');
function button_action(){
if(store_video.paused){
  store_video.play();
  btn_store.innerHTML = "Contacto:hola@vrsalud.com.ar";
}
else {
  store_video.pause();
  btn_store.innerHTML = "Play Intro";
}
}

</script>
  </body>

.container {
  position: relative;
}

button

{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00FFFF ;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);

}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my little english...
Best Regards
Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is on responsiveness, I would like to put light on something called as **Bootstrap**. Bootstrap is a CSS framework that allows you to build responsive websites.

You have to import the links in your HTML file between  section. Here is the quick link to get started if you want to import the **MaxCDN** links quickly: [W3Schools Bootstrap Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp)
(Scroll down in that link to see the Bootstrap links to import)

**Step 1:** Add the bootstrap links to your HTML page

**Step 2:**

To this piece of HTML:

```
<video width="1920" height="1080" loop id="video_sample">
<source src="VRHealthWeb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

You can add this:

```
<div class="container">
   <video width="1920" height="1080" loop id="video_sample">
   <source src="VRHealthWeb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
   </video>
</div>
```

**What it does?**

**Container** is basically a bootstrap classname that adds a padding and to the HTML control automatically. Although this is not the only way to add responsiveness, I have shown you the quick recipe of it. Try resizing your browser window and then see the effect.

After this you will require few CSS classes to add to your stylesheet. This is simplest way to add quick responsiveness to your HTML controls.

Hope this helps.